# Spring IoC: Dependency not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-ioc

This is my code:

```java
@Bean("incidencies")
public Jaxb2Marshaller incidenciesMarshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.visor.api.common.domain.incidencies");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public IncidenciesWebServiceGatewaySupport incidenciesClientConnector(
    @Qualifier("incidencies") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,
    ...
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method incidenciesClientConnector in cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.visor.api.common.configuration.VisorApiConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller' that could not be found.
```

I don't quite figure out what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe something wrong with Spring version or configuration. If there is no any other beans of `Jaxb2Marshaller` - try to remove name parameter from `@Bean` annotation and remove `@Qualifier` to check if injection works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `Qualifier` with `Bean`.

```
@Bean()
@Qualifier("incidencies") 
public Jaxb2Marshaller incidenciesMarshaller() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought `@Bean("name")` is equivalent to `@Bean + @Qualifier("name")`